# Multiple Azure Storage Integration with Rails 6 application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, rails-activestorage

I have used Azure Active Storage for all the user files that are uploaded on my application developed using Rails v6. Works perfectly fine.

Now I wanted to make a copy of the files that are getting uploaded on my application to **Another** Azure storage account. How can I go about this approach. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-ruby in your backend.

I was copying files from one container to another in the same storage account so I could do something like:

```
blob_service.copy_blob(azure_storage_container_name, destination_blob, container_name, blob.name)
```

But there is also:

```
blob_service.copy_blob_from_uri(azure_storage_container_name, blob.name, source_uri)
```

which I was considering if we did it between separate accounts.